# InAppBilling - Is there any way to set my existing users as premium?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

My app is currently paid and I have thousands of paid users.
however, I want to make it free with some limitations and sell premium upgrade for new users. So far so good.
But how can I set the thousands of current users as premium, since they already paid for the application?
Is there any way to set my existing users as premium?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Release a lite version of the app.

Comment: I already have a lite version, but I would like to discontinue this lite version and keep only a free version and sell the premium upgrade

Comment: Ohh, that I cabt help you with, I have no experience with that sort of thing, sorry.

Comment: OK. Alternatively I think I could set a user flag in the realtime database, but I think the right thing would be to set it as a SKU on InAppBilling API

Comment: Just an idea, If you do not have a lot of users, update your premium app and tell users about the update, ask their email and send them promo codes via email. but be sure to handle duplicate requests.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but besides having thousands of users, it would not be wise to take users out of their comfort zone, as many users may not understand how to proceed with the promotional code.

Answer (score 0):

As I have not found a way to set all the current users as premium, I created in the firebase database in the users node a premium flag to identify the users who have already made the purchase of the application. Hope this answer can be useful for someone else.